# Invisible text in EditText on MapActivity

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-edittext

I have a problem with an android application I am developing.

I have an `Activity` with an `EditText` at the top of the screen, and a map taking over the rest of the space. The problem is that the `EditText` don't show any of the text I put in it. You can focus the `EditText` and type more text or even select the text that the app put in the `EditText` and copy it. When you paste it in another application, you can see that it is the text that suppose to be in the `EditText`. So I know that the text is there, but I really don't understand why the text isn't shown.

I have tried changing the background color of the `EditText` (which worked, but text still is invisible) and changing the text color (which changed nothing). Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/findingSatellites"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10" />

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/bigMap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="someapikey"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The map is shown correctly. Can you help me?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried to comment out the map from the XML file (and code) and now the text inside the `EditText` is rendered. I also tried to comment out my MapOverlay, but the text is still now shown. I tried replacing the `EditText` with a `TextView` with the same result. How come no text is rendered when there is a map in the `Activity`?

**UPDATE2:**
I have modified my xml according to your suggestions. This is what I have now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/statusLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="@string/findingSatellites" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/statusLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/bigMap"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:apiKey="0ZGxti1I-qNSsMmsOCqnbPsnNG7Sl4U2aHvDc-Q"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It still doesn't render any text.

Here is a picture of what is happening:

[image: The EditText with some of the invisible text marked]

Comment: i think  create its width wrap_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. Colors on android is represented by integers as ARGB, and I'm comming from a HTML/CSS background which only uses RGB. This made me set the alphachannel for the textcolor to 0, meaning fully transparent. I am really stupid! Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: So what exactly did you change?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a `RelativeLayout` to position the `MapView` below the `EditText`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="@string/findingSatellites" />

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/bigMap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="someapikey"
        android:layout_below="@id/status"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This give me the exact same result. The map is shown below the EditText, but the text inside the EditText is not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Put `editText` in another layout.

Comment: I have tried placing both the EditText and MapView in two separate LinearLayout's which is inside the RelativeLayout as antew sugested. This gives me the same result. I have also tried to put the EditText in a separate LinearLayout, which didn't work either.